# Send IP packets between two Arduino or two Raspberry boards

Tags: pi-3, networking, hardware, arduino

I have two Arduino boards and I want to do a small project with them.
I want them the do the following:

Firstly, I want to send an IP packet through the network from the first Arduino to the other. When the second receive the message, I want the first one to blink a LED.
(I want to connect my own Arduino through an Ethernet cable to my modem/router
and a friend of mine will connect his Arduino in the same way to his, and i want to make them communicate)

Secondly, I want to be able to record my own voice and send it, from the first Arduino to the second Arduino, which will be able to play it.

Note: somebody told me that the second requirement of mine is not an Arduino project and can be done with a Raspberry Pi. Can someone explain me why it is not an Arduino project?

I would like some guidelines to start my project.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But please write proper sentences so I do not have to puzzle what you mean. It will also people more motivate to help you for free. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: Hi @khalid. Fist of all, your project needs programming and network knowledge that you may not have at the time, consider starting with something easier. A bare Arduino board does not have Ethernet, audio input and output, while a Raspberry Pi most of the Raspberry Pi boards have them, thus using two Raspberry Pi boards seems easier.

Comment: Hello. Detecting a button press and flashing an LED is well covered in many tutorials. Joining two devices across the internet when you may not know their IP address or might not want to have to re-configure the gateway is more advanced. I'd suggest starting with getting your light to flash on the same board first; then on two boards on the same LAN and finally investigate moving to the WAN using a VPN or dynamic-DNS (for example). You might get better results by breaking the project down like this and asking more specific questions (after doing some of your own research) on each step.